# Is it possible to find all my questions which have answers from specific user?

Tags: support, search

Is it possible to find all my questions which have answers from specific user?

I would like to see if I forgot to accept some of his answers.

Comment: *Only* that user? Sounds a bit underhanded, why not just go through your questions properly and check whether or not the have an answer that worked?

Comment: Only that user complains. My opinion it that my feedback is adequate to response.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: [SEDE](http://meta.superuser.com/tags/data-explorer/info) seems like a reasonable tool to do this. You can try to create a query for this by yourself, but it seems likely that some such queries [already exist](https://www.google.com/search?q=questions+answered+by+user+site:data.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search only acts on one user.

The search for all your open questions with at least one answer and is unaccepted is `user:104103  answers:1  hasaccepted:no closed:no`

There's no syntax for "where question is by X and answer is by Y"

*However*

> Only that user complains. My opinion it that my feedback is adequate to response

Feels problematic - *While* you aren't obliged to select an answer, you also shouldn't be selecting answers only cause users complain.

There's an *implicit* social contract for people to select the answers that worked for them, and a certain understanding that 'asking' people to select *their* answer as the correct one is not very classy.

Selecting an answer also keeps community from bumping up your question periodically. So, meh, if you need to go through your answers, you have about 150. Its worth reviewing them.

Comment: I am selecting answers when they deserve this. This user opposes this and I was wish to check. If it is impossible -- then it is impossible. Concerning social contracts -- I know everything about it myself, but thanks.

Comment: @Dims - So go through ALL your questions which have unaccepted answers.  You shouldn't just target questions answered by that specific user.  *You have a moderator saying doing so is problematic.*  You could trigger reversal scripts if you do that.

Comment: Hmm, Ramhound raises an interesting point. If Fred answered dozens of Barney's questions over the course of several years, and Barney accepts dozens of Fred's answers in a very short period of time, will the system treat that as serial voting and reverse it? Journeyman Geek and @Mokubai, do you have any knowledge or other thoughts regarding that issue?